# Find Undocumented Functions on a REST API

Tags: rest

I think the answer is 'NO', but I really do not know the answer to this.  Is there a way to find undocumented REST functions on a REST API?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange question, but the only answer is NO.

Or bruteforce, but, I guess, you don't want to do it.

Comment: I am using a REST API and the documentation is not the best.  I'm tired of watching the web application traffic, and was hoping I could walk the root up... but it seemed far fetched, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on...

If the service fulfills the REST constraints (uniform interface / HATEOAS in this case), then you can find every "function" as hyperlinks in the HTTP responses.

If the service does not fulfill the REST constraints, then we aren't talking about REST just a CRUDish RPC.